# (Sql + Python) df array to string with single quotes?

Tags: python, sql, arrays, string, quote

Goal: how to convert (111, 222, 333) to ('111', '222', '333') for an sql query in Python?

What I have done so far:

I am calling a csv file to a df:
`dataset = pd.read_csv('simple.csv')
print(dataset)`

LIST
0     111
1     222
2     333

`List11 = dataset.LIST.apply(str)
print(List1)`

0    111
1    222
2    333

Name: OPERATION, dtype: object

`myString = ",".join(List1)
print(myString)`

111,222,333

`sql = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE list IN (%s)" %myString`

This does not work. Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`format()`:](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

```
list1 = ('111', '222', '333')
myString = ",".join("'{0}'".format(elem) for elem in list1)
print(myString)
```

gives

```
'111','222','333'
```

Comment: After I obtained a list -- it worked like a charm! :) dataset['LIST'].values.tolist() Thanks alot !

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and verify if it helps-

sql = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE list IN (%s)" % ",".join(map(myString,List1))

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility that it will works.

```
myString = "','".join(List1)
sql = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE list IN ('%s')" %myString
```